# What is the best approach in adding projects on a Domain Driven Design DDD having multiple databases?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, web-applications, domain-driven-design, dddd

> **Solution Projects:**

- **API** - contains controller and exposes API
- **Application** - contains specific business rule only applied for the an API
- **Common** - contains constants
- **Domain** - it contains the entities which uses the onion architecture of DDD
- **Infrastructure** - handles external API transactions
- **Persistence** - Domain to Database configuration and mappings

I have a set of projects in my solution *(see above)*, however, the whole solution transacts to only 1 database. Now, I have a plan to integrate another database, **What is the best approach in adding projects on a Domain Driven Design DDD having multiple databases?**

Initially, I'm thinking of adding another pesistence project but I'm thinking it will require domains. I'm not sure if it is right to mix the domains mapped with different databases. **Can someone tell me how to approach this?**

Comment: Sounds like a new `Bounded Context`?  Am I assuming the current implementation is a single `Bounded Context` (BC)?  I'm currently having a play about in a slightly different scenario using `WebAPI`. I think a domain (or maybe BC) should have its own database.  Does this map closely to Microservices?  Currently still looking at things - and it all works nicely at the minute.

Comment: There is no single answer like "Do *this* for DDD with multiple databases and the force will be with you. Always.". Depending on your project needs adding another database may or may not change the architecture.

Comment: yes @Andez it is a bounded context

Comment: Personally, with my current understanding of DDD in the Enterprise, I would have a separate vertical layer per bounded context - although that might be overkill for your scenario.  I feel it makes good practice.  I am still reading Eric Evans blue book and also Vaughan Vernons red book as well as Scott Millets Patterns Principles and Practices of DDD - been reading them all for the last 2 years.  Like Fabjan mentions, depends on your project needs - I started with the view of a project per BC - and ended up with a single database although each BC has its own set of Entity Framework repos

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's a new database or a new project should not matter at all. You have to translate the functionality into your ubiquitous language and see how that fits into your application now.
You'll end up answering questions like:
* Is this a new feature or one that complements an existing one
* Does this feature even belong in this domain
* Are there new entities, aggregates and value types needed to express this feature

All of those DDD questions don't care how serialization happen or doesn't. The specifics of serialization falls outside the purview of your Domain.